# Django render view based on choice of radio button

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a django project where I have to render view according to the choice selected in radio button i.e if student is selected it has to go to one page and if faculty is selceted it should go to another page
forms.py

```
DISPLAY_CHOICES = (
(1, "Student"),
(2, "Faculty")
)        

class Wru(forms.Form):
display_type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, 
choices=DISPLAY_CHOICES)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    form=Wru(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
          if form.fields['display_type'].choices[1]:
            return home(request)
          else:
            return simple_upload(request)
    return render(request, 'acads/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the redirect function.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

```
def index(request):
    form=Wru(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
          if form.fields['display_type'].choices[1]:
             return redirect('/url/of/homepage')
          else:
             return redirect('url/of/simple_upload/)
    return render(request, 'acads/index.html', {'form': form})
```